# What does "Zoom 3.6.0" mean in user agent string?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, zoom-sdk

According to developers.whatismybrowser.com, below user agent was IE11 on Windows 7.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Media Center PC 6.0; Zoom 3.6.0; Zoom 3.6.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

I would like to know what does "Zoom 3.6.0" mean in user agent string.
Was it running from Zoom application?

Comment: Did you try to fetch the above user agent on your machine? I try to get the user agent for IE 11 using `navigator.userAgent` but I am not getting that `zoom 3.6.0` in it. I also check the said [website](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/internet-explorer) and found that it also does not mention it. If possible, can you please inform us how you fetch that user agent string? It can help to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Hi. I test browser agent string on my pc and not contains zoom 3.6.0 too. but IIS logs still records barely users agent string has cotain zoom 3.6.0

Comment: It can be possible that some application is overriding the user agent string. You can try to check the application code may give some hints.

Comment: I get this when inspecting logs when a VB6 app that has an old IE control embedded in it accesses the site: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; Zoom 3.6.0)

Comment: @KolonUK Hi. Thank for information. I'll check it